# c:out JSTL tag doesn't work for me

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I've just recently been trying to get into JSTL and I'm experiencing some problems with it..

This is a tag in my hello.JSP:

```
<p>Greetings, it is now <c:out value="${now}"/></p>
```

And it's supposed to display the current time, but the output that I do get is:

```
Greetings, it is now ${now}
```

The tag is written from a SpringSource tutorial so it should be correct, but the logic seems to be skipped... don't know why this is. 
I have the jstl.jar in a reference library and

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

is implemented in a separate JSP-file header that is included in the hello.JSP file.

If you haven't guessed I'm a total noob in this environment so the solution may be very simple. If anyone could give me some pointers on what the problem might be I would greatly appreciate it!

Best regards
-Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSTL, `now` is not a predefined variable.

In the SpringSource docs you are reading you might have missed where they assigned the variable `now` a value like `new Date()`, most likely in a `<c:set>` tag.  I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: wow... I feel pretty stupid.. it turned out that in the tutorial they first showed how to display the value of a variable in a view, the c:out tag. The logic behind which declared what "now" was came a bit after.. =P
So you're right Ray, I had just missed it. I wished they would have presented it in the other order though. =)

Comment: Agreed that the tutorial is out of order.  No need to feel stupid about that one.